# OnClick Fragment Transactions Does Nothing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, transactions

So I am having a little trouble with Fragment transactions. I have navigation drawer and I implemented the code written In the docs for Fragment Transactions but when I click the button,nothing happen.

MainFeedActivity.class:

```
public class MainFeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainFeedBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainFeedBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMainFeed.toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_memories, R.id.nav_snack_memories, R.id.nav_favorite_memories)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main_feed);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 // Create new fragment and transaction
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_memories, GalleryFragment.class, null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main_feed);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();

    }



}
```

Buton onClick in MainFeedActivity.class:

```
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             // Create new fragment and transaction
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment
            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_memories, GalleryFragment.class, null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

Gallery Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gallery_fragment"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

GalleryFragment Java:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentGalleryBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textGallery;
        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: check by replacing transaction.replace(R.id.nav_memories, GalleryFragment.class, null); to transaction.replace(R.id.nav_memories, new GalleryFragment(), null);

Comment: I replaced it, however, it's still doing nothing..